# How to create a listview of key and value from Firebase?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am new to Firebase and from watching some tutorials and reading the docs, I made the app to display the values of a node in a listview. But what I want to do is to display both the key and value in the listview.
How can I do that?

What I did:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final String med = "Meth";

    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://fir-test-d6253.firebaseio.com/"+med);

    final FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {


            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);

        }
    };

    mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);

}
```

}`

Database:

```
 - fir-test-d6253addclose
    -  Meth
        - Store1: "1"
        - Store2: "10"
    - Morphine
        - Store1: "5"
        - Store2: "10"
        - Store3: "10"
```

The output now is:

```
 - 1
 - 10
```

What I want:

```
 - Store1 1
 - Store2 10
```

or is there any other way instead of using firebaseui?

Comment: Is this just an example so that you can learn about firebase, or is this database structure what you plan to use?  Is it important to you that the data should be able to be updated in realtime?

Comment: i want to use this structure.It is important to be updated in real time. This will be my database for further improvements in the app. More childs will be added to each category like more stores can be added to meth...

Comment: Sounds illegal... =T

Comment: Its just an example :P   I cant use classes as the stores will be increasing so changing the class will not be possible. (i think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly post the Adapter code let me help. Else use this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) to retrieve the data and display in listview. DataSnapshot parameters int the functions will have the key and its value.